# Error related to AUTHWINRTWP.DLL IBM MobileFirst Windows Universal App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1-universal

I am trying to upload windows 8 universal build to Windows store and getting below certification error.

**The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=OutputDebugStringA. Module=api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-1.dll. File=AuthWinRTwp.dll.**

I am using 7.1.0.00-20160528-1648 version.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new MobileFirst project and in that there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. See [APAR PI57716](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI57716). This should have been fixed in the version of MobileFirst you're using. Did you upgrade your MobileFirst Studio from a previous version ? If so, please recreate the Native API (or environment if your app is hybrid)

Comment: Hi Srik, thanks for the reply, i have recreated the environment even created a new project, still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Is your application set to debug mode? Perhaps this prevents you from submitting the application. This does not seem to be related to IBM MobileFirst.

Comment: Hi Idan, my application is not set to debug mode, I have checked the build configuration, it is set to release mode.

Answer (score 0):

This Wack test mainly vertify that your app must use the [**APIs for Windows Store apps**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211369.aspx) (Windows Runtime or supported Win32 APIs).

Just make sure your app was compiled as a release build not a debug build, since the debug build of your app will fail this test even if your app uses only APIs for Windows Store apps.

For more details, you might refer to [**Windows App Certification Kit tests for Windows Store apps**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657973.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We tested the above scenario with latest MFP 7.1 plugin with windows8universal hybrid app.And do not see any issue.you can share the appx file so that we can investigate to find the cause.